# Rezise LVM on VM VMWare Ubuntu

Tags: server, partitioning, lubuntu, vmware, disk

I am needing to expand a disk in an Ubuntu virtual machine in VMWare but I am not clear about the procedure since I do not control Linux very well, the partition is logical from what I have been able to see:/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv

What would be the correct procedure to do it? I don't want to risk data loss as it is a critical service. Additionally I attach a couple of screenshots with the information of the volumes, thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHoGF.png)

Regards.

Comment: You haven’t given us much to go on although you clearly have LVM in use for /. I have always found this link helpful https://www.tecmint.com/extend-and-reduce-lvms-in-linux/

Answer (score 0):

I attach another screenshot where it is shown how the disks are partitioned. I would need to extend the LVM, I see that it depends on several partitions of several disks, how can I extend it? What should I take into consideration? SQL data is currently stored in this LVM, thanks.

Regards[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKysc.png)